# Get which or-condition is met in an if-statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following Python if-statement:

```
if element1 in list[2] or element2 in list[2] or 3 in list[2]:
   do some more if-statements...
else:
   print something...
```

Is it possible to print (or get in some way) which of the or-conditions are met (if there are any)? Because there are other if-statements in the if-clause, I don't want to use three different if-statements, which would be one solution. But this will end up in nearly 12 different if-statement. I just want to log which condition is met for further analysis. I googled of course, but found nothing so for.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
Use case: try to implement a search algorithm with "AND" and "OR" function. I'm sure could be written much better and cleaner but for now counts what works ;-)

Comment: Python does this magic thing called short circuiting when using or statements. this means if the first statement (in your case element1 in list[2]) is True, then the other statements in the if will be ignored as it will always return True. Due to this, there is no way of doing exactly what you want. I would recommend evaluating them all first as suggested by MadPhysicist (if you really NEED to know which values are T/F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the boolean values to names:

```
a = element1 in list[2]
b = element2 in list[2]
c = 3 in list[2]
if a or b or c:
    print(f"{element1} {'in' if a else 'not in'} list[2]")
    print(f"{element2} {'in' if b else 'not in'} list[2]")
    print(f"3 {'in' if c else 'not in'} list[2]")
```

This removes any benefits of short-circuiting though, since all the expressions need to be evaluated.

In python 3.8+ you can use assignment expressions:

```
if (a := (element1 in list[2])) or \
   (b := (element2 in list[2])) or \
   (c := (3 in list[2])):
    try:
        print(f"{element1} {'in' if a else 'not in'} list[2]")
        print(f"{element2} {'in' if b else 'not in'} list[2]")
        print(f"3 {'in' if c else 'not in'} list[2]")
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Keep in mind that this approach has the opposite problem: some names may not have been assigned because of short circuiting. You won't know the result for any name past the first false one.

Another way, if you really have a lot of conditions, is to build a list instead of naming each individual one:

```
test = [element1, element2, 3]
x = [t in list[2] for t in test]
if any(x):
    for t, r in zip(test, x):
        print(f"{t} {'in' if r else 'not in'} list[2]")
```

You can even go so far as to use sets:

```
test = {element1, element2, 3}
s2 = set(list[2])
x = test & s2
if x:
    print('{x!r} in list[2]')
    if y := test - x:
        print('{y} not in list[2]')
```

The choice depends on your specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Your suggested solution with the list seems to work and has also the advantge that I can define the elements in a list which is pretty helpful for the whole code (try to implement a search algorithm with "AND" and "OR" function). Even if I don't understand the code completly yet... ;-)

Comment: Seems to work and I think I understand the code now. There is just one problem left. The search of the keyword in "x = [t in list[2] for t in test]" is case sensitive which it shouldn't be. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @plategt. If you make sure that everything in `list[2]` is lowercase/casefolded, replace `t in list[2]...` with `t.casefold() in list[2]...`

Comment: Thank you. I implemented it but I regonized another problem. Before I used "element in list" which was more variable for the search. With the new solution if I search for "tiger" it wouldn't find "tigers" for example. I need to make sure that the term will be found if it occurs, even with letters before and after. Like using a * around the search term.  The lower case problem seems easy to solve with your suggestion. But the other one?

Comment: @plategt. At this point I would recommend doing some research into applying methods like `str.__contains__` to each element (vs. `list.__contains__` which you are using now). Possibly even regex, but that is probably overkill in this situation. Certainly out of scope for this one question.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted cleaner code then I would suggest putting the if statement checks inside a function and using a logger to log the truth of the statement.

```
import logging

def elem_in_list(elem, list):
    if elem in list[2]:
        logging.info(f"{elem} is in list")
        return True
    logging.info(f"{elem} is not in list")
    return False

if elem_in_list(element1, list) or elem_in_list(element2, list) or elem_in_list(element3, list):
    # do more if statements
else:
    print(something)
```

This is perhaps a cleaner way of doing it, but you cannot get around using a load of if statements for comparisons as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Wanted to use this as easy solution. Doesn't work because of the mentioned short circuiting. If the first condition is met, there will be no more logging. Though, i have to test every statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this, if I wanted leverage short-circuiting:

Create a `condition` variable with a known starting value. Then create an **else-if** chain with all your conditions, and for each one set a different value for the `condition` variable if the boolean expression evaluates to `True`. Then, create an **if** statement after the **else-if** block, which checks whether the `condition` variable's value has  changed.

```
condition = 0
if (expression)==(expression):
    condition = 1
elif (expression)==(expression):
    condition = 2
elif (expression)==(expression):
    condition = 3

if condition:
   # perform common actions here
   if condition == 1:
       print(f"Condition met was condition ONE!")
```

You could also execute any condition-specific code in the **else-if** block, instead of executing it in the last **if** block, if you think that would be more readable in your case.

You could also move the common code that needs to be executed in multiple cases to a function.

```
if (expression)==(expression):
    # case 1 code here
    common_code()
elif (expression)==(expression):
    # case 2 code here
    common_code()
elif (expression)==(expression):
    # case 3 code here
    # Maybe this one does not need to call common_code()? This solution is fairly flexible.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if element1 in list[2] or element2 in list[2] or 3 in list[2]:
    if element1 in list[2]:
        print('element1 found in list[2]')
    if element2 in list[2]:
        print('element1 found in list[2]')
    if element3 in list[2]:
        print('element1 found in list[2]')
    #=== do some more if-statements...
else:
   #== print something...
```

Inside the grouped `if` condition you can check which condition was actually fulfilled.
I don't know better way to do this.

Comment: You forgot to put ```''``` around the strings

Comment: Corrected, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a Python dictionary for this purpose. As an example:

```
list1=[list2,list2,list2]
list2=[3,4,6]
list3=[4,6,7]
element1=0
element2=0

if element1 in list1[2] or element2 in list1[2] or 3 in list1[2]:
  dict_conditions={"Condition 1":str(element1 in list1[2]),"Condition 2":str(element2 in list1[2]) ,"Condition 3":str(3 in list1[2])}
  print(dict_conditions)
```

Which would print the following output:

```
{'Condition 1': 'False', 'Condition 2': 'False', 'Condition 3': 'True'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply by making the result of each condition a name/number:

```
>>> res = ((element1 in lst[2] and 1) or
...        (element2 in lst[2] and 2) or
...        (3 in lst[2] and 3))
>>> if res:
...     print('condition', res, 'succeeded')
...
condition 2 succeeded
```

If you're using python >= 3.8 this can be wrapped up more neatly, like this:

```
if (res := (element1 in lst[2] and 1) or
           (element2 in lst[2] and 2) or
           (3 in lst[2] and 3)):
    print('condition', res, 'succeeded')
```

If none of the conditions is true, `res` will be `False`, otherwise it will be the name/number of whichever condition succeeded.

---

The reason why this works is explained in the python reference for [boolean expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is
> returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is
> returned.

Thus, for the above approach to work properly, the name/number must evaluate to true (so just avoid using empty strings, zero, or anything for which `bool(n)` is false).